# How can it be showed the Parallelogram Law of vector addition in a circuit made on circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, tikz-circuit-lib

I want to show the resulting vector of the sum, `v_{ab}`, with the *Parallelogram Law* of the vector adition as it is showed on the first figure:

[image]

The circuit was made on circuitikz. The code is the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\def\DIR{0,120,-120}
\foreach \i in 
\DIR {
\draw (\i:2.5) to[sV=$ $, *-o] (0,0);
}
\draw
(0,0)node[xshift=0.5*10,yshift=-10*0.866]{d}
(0:2.5)node[xshift=10,yshift=0]{a}
(120:2.5)node[xshift=-0.5*10,yshift=10*0.866]{b}
(-120:2.5)node[xshift=-0.5*10,yshift=-10*0.866]{c}
(0:1.25)node[xshift=0,yshift=20]{$v_{ad}$}
(120:1.25)node[xshift=-0.5*10-14,yshift=-10*0.866-7]{$v_{bd}$}
(-120:1.25)node[xshift=0.5*10+14,yshift=-10*0.866-7]{$v_{cd}$}
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which generate the following second image:

[image]

How can the vector `v_{ab}` be showed with the parallelogram law in the circuit made on circuitikz?

Comment: If your question is how to combine the two pictures, that's easy: just put one (or both) in scopes (circuitikz IS a tikzpicture).  Of course, the vector addition is done is phase space and the schematic has no physical meaning.  You might add a curved <-> line between a and b labeled v_ab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about circuits, this is only to show that you can use the ordinary `tikz` command within `circuitikz`:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw[dashed,green] (60:2.5) to (0:2.5);
\draw[dashed,blue] (60:2.5) to (120:2.5);
\node[black,circle,text width=.13cm,inner sep=0,fill=black]at (60:2.5)(circb){};
\draw[red, Stealth-] (circb)node[xshift=0.5*10,yshift=10*0.866]{b} to (0,0);
\node at (70:1.75) {$v_{ab}$};
\def\DIR{0,120,-120} 
\foreach \i in \DIR { \draw (\i:2.5) to[sV=$ $, *-o] (0,0); } 
\draw (0,0)node[xshift=0.5*10,yshift=-10*0.866]{e} (0:2.5)node[xshift=10,yshift=0]{a} (120:2.5)node[xshift=-0.5*10,yshift=10*0.866]{c} (-120:2.5)node[xshift=-0.5*10,yshift=-10*0.866]{d} (0:1.25)node[xshift=0,yshift=20]{$v_{ae}$} (120:1.25)node[xshift=-0.5*10-14,yshift=-10*0.866-7]{$v_{ce}$} (-120:1.25)node[xshift=0.5*10+14,yshift=-10*0.866-7]{$v_{de}$} ;
\end{circuitikz} 
\end{document}
```

[image]